# Where can I get a Canon 7D / 7D Mark II card slot cover replacement part?

Tags: canon-7d, repair-parts

I own a Canon 7D Mark II. I broke off the card slot cover and need a replacement. Where could I find this? What would it cost?

[image]

Comment: Is the camera still under warranty?

Answer (score 3):

> Do you have this? Cost?

I think you've got the wrong idea about this site. Photo.SE is a question and answer site, not a vendor of any kind. Nevertheless, I did a little looking around and found two sources for the card cover for a 7D, with prices in the $20-30 range. The 7D Mark II cover is apparently not the same part, and I didn't come across any vendor selling that part, but if you can find one I'd expect the price to be in the same range. (Covers for various other EOS models were also mostly under $30.)

[A Canon Knowledgebase article](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART121398&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1455676644054) explains that Canon doesn't sell parts online, but that you can order parts by calling Canon's customer service people. In the US, the phone number is 1-800-828-4040. I think that's probably the best bet for getting exactly the right part.

Comment: I just compared the covers of my 7D and 7DII. They're not the same. Different shape as well as different width where they attach to the camera.

Comment: Thanks for that info @MichaelClark. I'll remove the sources (because who knows how long they'll be correct anyway) and just leave the price info.

Comment: I accidentally broke off the memory card cover on my nearly new Canon 7d Markii.  I sent the camera to the authorized Canon Center in New Jersey.  I figured it would be about $50 or so for such a simple repair.  They emailed me saying it would be $219 for the repair and $14 to ship back to me.  I told them just to send the unrepaired cover back to me.  I've spent nearly $15,000 at B+H on a 7D, two 7D Markii cameras, $9,000 on Canon lenses, tripods, camera bags, straps, memory cards, and on and on over the last 2 years.

Comment: Where's Canon's customer appreciation. I contacted B+H to see if their repair department could do the simple part replacement but they blew me off.

Comment: Don't blame Canon for the service you get (or don't) from B&H. As far as Canon goes, though, have you considered a CPS membership? With all that equipment it seems crazy not to pay a little bit annually for the repair discount (20% off for gold members, 30% off for platinum), free shipping, and faster turnaround. Also, did you call Canon and ask about buying the part you need? And is it possible that you need more than just a new cover? It's hard to tell from your pic, but it looks like the body might be damaged.